# pygments problems in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, pygments, maruku

I use jekyll in github pages.
http://juanpabloaj.github.com/

But, when I add the syntax.css file for pygments

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/syntax.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

[default.html](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/juanpabloaj.github.com/blob/master/_layouts/default.html)

jekyll don't show the syntax, I have set on the pygments line

```
 pygments:    true
```

[pygments-true](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/juanpabloaj.github.com/blob/master/_config.yml#L12)

Comment: I'm getting the same issue! :(

Comment: Ah, I had to make sure I specified `markdown: maruku` for some reason in the `_config.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed pygments locally per the instructions here 
https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/install

Comment: I have pygments installed, my problem ocurred locally and in github

Comment: Ok so just in case I have misunderstood, you have to put `pygments: true` in your `_config.yml` file.  As far as I know, your css has nothing to do with whether or not jekyll uses pygments for code highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure I specified `markdown: maruku` for some reason in the `_config.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/syntax.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get syntax highlighting working in the latest version you need to update markdown to the [new parser](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0) in _config.yml:

```
markdown: kramdown
```